# How do I get my AirPlay mirroring to take up my entire TV screen?

Tags: macos, appletv, airplay

I have a 2011 27" iMac that currently has Mountain Lion installed on it, and I am trying to get the AirPlay mirroring to take up my entire 1080p widescreen TV.  How do I get that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the *Match Desktop Size To* setting in the AirPlay menubar item to **Apple TV**

[image: Airplay menu]

If that doesn't work, it may be that AirPlay is outputting at 720p and your TV isn't scaling - perhaps try a stretch or scale mode on your TV.

Comment: I already did that. I was trying to play a DVD from "DVD Player", and when I set the desktop size to AppleTV it only takes up about 1/3 of the screen starting in the upper left corner. And when I set the desktop size to the AppleTV when my iMac is not running the DVD Player, it will take up 2/3 of the screen starting at the top and centered.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Open Display Preferences" in the AirPlay menu (as shown above). 
Set the resolution on your TV to 1080p. 
The key, at least in my case, and I suspect in yours, is to click "overscan correction", which will get that last 1~5% black border to go away.